# Почему блоки прижимаются к нижней границе родительского блока

Tags: html, css

Задача: расставить div в строку.
При указании

```
.content { display: inline-block; }
```

блоки прижимаются к нижней границе родителя, а надо чтоб к верхней.

[пример на cssdesk.com](http://cssdesk.com/bCufK)

---

Нашел выход: родителю поставить

```
.container { display: table;}
```

а детям:

```
.content {display: table-cell;}
```

но думаю есть решения изящнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `div.cont` нужно добавить свойство `vertical-align: top;`.

Пример: http://cssdesk.com/9RyKU

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 4):

Это имели в виду?

```
div.cont {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: пока сохранял и ссылку копировал, опередили немного))

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так сделать

```
  body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

div.container {
  background-color: #ccc; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.cont {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

div.cont:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6WE6/3/

Comment: хорошее решение если нужна поддержка вплоть до 7 версии, плюсую.